# spring and junit bean injection and instantiating

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have multiple test classes, which have inside `autowired` field - instance of `databaseConnection` and `dataSource`.

Something like

```
<bean id="dataSource">
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:..."/>
    ....
</bean>

<bean id="databaseConnection">
    <constructor-arg name="connection" value="# { dataSource.getConnection() }"/>
    ....
</bean>
```

My base test class has standard annotation

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(value = {"path/to/context.xml"})
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
public abstract class BaseRepositoryTest { }
```

As far as I know, `junit` creates new instance of class for every test inside class. So I think it wires beans everytime. Am I right?

So my question is does `spring` initializes context everytime - I mean initializes `datasource`, `databaseConnection` beans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is no if extending same base integration class.

All classes extending BaseRepositoryTest will reuse context once it is created.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testing-ctx-management